# How to log back to Strapi after logging out

Tags: strapi, headless-cms

I created a strapi API and then closed the server. Once I try to reopen the server with npm run start I do not have edit access to my content typesbuilder. It also asks me to- The autoReload feature is required to use this plugin. Start your server with `strapi develop` and I did this to no avail. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I just had to restart the server with npm run develop